# How can I ensure that the sprite is dropped exactly where the mouse is clicked, without tilting?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project where I have a canvas and I'm trying to create box objects on it. The box creation code is working, but I'm facing an issue with the orientation of the box sprites. When I drop a box on the canvas, the sprite appears to be tilted.

[image]

When the user clicks on the canvas, a ray is cast from the camera to get the mouse position.

If the ray hits an object, the `_CheckCanDropObject` function is called to validate the drop position.

```
Ray ray = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo, Mathf.Infinity))
{           
    if (_CheckCanDropObject(ray, hitInfo))
    {
        BuildingController.CreateBox(new Vector3(hitInfo.point.x, hitInfo.point.y, WHConstants.AboveDefaultZ), buildingInventoryController.currentBlock.BlockSprite);
    }
}
```

If the drop position is valid, the `CreateBox` function is called to create a new box object.
The `CreateBox` function iterates through the children of the building and finds the floor plan.

```
public static void CreateBox(Vector3 position, UnityEngine.Sprite sprite)
{
    List<ICommand> commands = new List<ICommand>();
    foreach (CreatorItem child in GetBuilding().children)
    {
        if (child.name.Contains(WHConstants.FLOOR_PLAN))
        {
            CreatorItem floorPlan = child;
            float height = floorPlan.GetComponent<IHasDimension>().Dimension.Height;

            string name = NamingController.GetName(WHConstants.Box, floorPlan.uiItem.Foldout.Children());
            CreatorItemCreateCommand createCommand = new CreatorItemCreateCommand(new CreatorBoxFactory(position, sprite, height), name);
            ICommand createAndAddParentCommand = new CreateCreatorItemWithParentCommand(createCommand, floorPlan.Id);
            commands.Add(createAndAddParentCommand);
        }
    }
    ICommand createBox = new MultipleCommand(commands);
    UndoRedo.AddAndExecuteCommand(createBoxs);
    DeselectAll();
    CreatorUIController.UnSavedProgress = true;
}
```

It creates a new box using the `CreatorBoxFactory` and adds commands to create and parent the box.

```
public class CreatorBoxFactory : ICreatorItemFactory
{
    private Vector3 _position;
    private Sprite _sprite;
    private float _height;

    public CreatorBoxFactory(Vector3 position, Sprite sprite, float height)
    {
        _height = height;
        _position = position;
        _sprite = sprite;
    }

    public CreatorItem Create(string name, bool createGO = true)
    {
        Box item;
        GameObject Box = null;
        if (createGO)
        {
            UIItem uiItem = new BoxUIFactory().Create(name);
            Box = CreateBox();
            item = new Box(Box, uiItem);
        }
        else
        {
            item = new Box(null, null);
        }
        item.SetPosition(new Vector3(_position.x, _position.y, 0));
        item.SetDimension(WHConstants.DefaultBoxLength, _height, WHConstants.DefaultBox2DHeight);
        item.SetName(name);

        if (item.uiItem != null)
        {
            item.uiItem._delegate = item;
        }
        if (createGO)
        {
            item.SetTransformer();
        }
        return item;
    }

    private GameObject CreateBox()
    {
        GameObject boxGameObject = new GameObject();
        SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = boxGameObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        spriteRenderer.sprite = _sprite;

        Vector2 unit = ConvertCoordinate.PixelToUnit(spriteRenderer.sprite);

        BoxCollider lineCollider = boxGameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
        lineCollider.transform.parent = spriteRenderer.transform;
        lineCollider.size = new Vector3(unit.x, unit.y, 1f);
        lineCollider.center = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        boxGameObject.tag = WHConstants.METABLOCK;

        boxGameObject.transform.position = _position;
        boxGameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(WHConstants.DefaultBoxLength / unit.x, WHConstants.DefaultBox2DHeight / unit.y, 1);
        return boxGameObject;
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm new to Unity so looking to help to identify the cause of this rotation issue and understand how to correct it. Is there something I might be missing in my code? How can I ensure that the box sprite is dropped exactly where the mouse is clicked, without any tilting?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a parenting issue, I see that you adding a `createAndAddParentCommand`, but I don't see how do you parent created object. So if parent has any rotation, when child will inherit this rotation. In order to keep child in initial rotation (not affected by parent), it will need  to counter rotate. So add this after you parent child object, but change `childTransform` variable to your variable name:

```
childTransform.rotation = childTransform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(childTransform.parent.rotation);
```

Comment: createAndAddParentCommand is adding the command to create the box, it doesn't have any rotation